# Laravel\Socialite\Two\InvalidStateException

Tags: laravel

`Laravel Framework 8.4.0`
`PHP 7.3.9`
Только начал изучать Laravel и столкнулся с такой проблемой. Просмотрел кучу форумов, но так и не нашел решения. Кеш чистил.

Ошибка:

`Laravel\Socialite\Two\InvalidStateException http://localhost:8000/login/facebook/callback?code=AQCTuxanNlNhlYbx16VXKyGDOCKhDz2SjCzAX5Qsrf8DhJo9F-hd8Unm2ochAQmy2SRc5lbACckERsVuk_HydAHN5jBNhqwMjcMfiGrkP_YUPjdqDreXKMSyVwrGVmT0ayAJKO54uamF2kypaRlivCdGoEYxFHEHk-VvdrnTH-3F19n6R_gcXvk2S2zgI6gftYEJJXtKRAjI6jR_OmVEKaoGkDfwxlEEE26ZVbYuNH4YJ-gQmSZeFF547p__Pbh2B2CvEBaXNaewupe10wsauMpXLfZLgtoQt1zmUYaQi9FUBCmPH0fECpdlZZf68KfZ0aWfNTzGIrgAmRZTMtjOl1Hm&state=wtB5Zd93UZgPBJ1OcP1R03XDjt4BhwKz9P8TsDcQ`

Login Controller:

```
<?php
    namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
    
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
    use App\User;
    Use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;
    
    Use Auth;
    
    class LoginController extends Controller
    {
    
    
        use AuthenticatesUsers;
    
        /**
         * Where to redirect users after login.
         *
         * @var string
         */
        protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;
    
        /**
         * Create a new controller instance.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
        }
    
        public function redirectToProvider()
        {
            return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();
        }
    
        public function handleProviderCallback()
        {
            $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
    
           dd($user);
        }
    }

> services.php

    <?php
    
    return [
        
    
        'mailgun' => [
            'domain' => env('MAILGUN_DOMAIN'),
            'secret' => env('MAILGUN_SECRET'),
            'endpoint' => env('MAILGUN_ENDPOINT', 'api.mailgun.net'),
        ],
    
        'postmark' => [
            'token' => env('POSTMARK_TOKEN'),
        ],
    
        'ses' => [
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION', 'us-east-1'),
        ],
    
        'facebook' => [
            'client_id' => env('FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID'),
            'client_secret' => env('FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET'),
            'redirect' => env('FACEBOOK_REDIRECT_URI'),
        ],
    ];

> web.php

    Route::get('/login/facebook', [LoginController::class, 'redirectToProvider']);
    Route::get('/login/facebook/callback', [LoginController::class, 'handleProviderCallback']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Нашел ответ здесь - `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e9Ae34lnwlA&ab_channel=StanislavBoyko`
..............